# How to Stop MDB pragmatically in wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, wildfly, messaging

I know a way to stop MDB in wildly by command line, which is setup the DeliveryActive status to be ture, then

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] cd deployment=jboss-helloworld-mdb.war/subsystem=ejb3/message-driven-bean=HelloWorldMDB

[standalone@localhost:9990 message-driven-bean=HelloWorldMDB] :stop-delivery
{"outcome" => "success"}

[standalone@localhost:9990 message-driven-bean=HelloWorldMDB] :start-delivery
{"outcome" => "success"}
```

According to this way, I think there must be a pragmatically way to invoke the MDB inside the EJB container, then do stop-delivery and start-delivery from MDB instance. But my issue is I cant find MDB by context.lookup(properties).
Is this a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through the JMX support of HornetQ locally or remotely.
Here is a pretty good example: [JEE7 + WildFly (HornetQ) - Pause queue from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942408/jee7-wildfly-hornetq-pause-queue-from-application)

You can do this from within your app as well of course.